# reverse string obfuscation that uses base64

Tags: javascript, base64, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I found below javascript code to convert a string to an obfuscated base64 string.

But how to convert it back?

```js
` 

function strobuscate(a) {
      return (a.split('').map(function(c, i) {
        return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + i % 80);
      }).join('');
    }

`
```

Comment: use atob to convert back. check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-window-atob-method/#:~:text=The%20Window%20atob()%20method,which%20represents%20the%20decoded%20string.

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi Yeah,i know it. but this base64 string is obfuscated, we need deobfuscate before base64decode.

Comment: What have you tried? Invert every operation in the inverse order.

Comment: @luk2302 hello,i tried to replace back "_" to "=", "." with "+" and "-" with "/". but i dont understand following code and how to reverse it.  ` return y + obbtoa(a.split('').map(function(e, i) {
    return String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(0) + i % t);
  }).join(''));`

Comment: Do you keep `t` somewhere? Otherwise might be quite hard, if I read correctly, since it seems to be a pseudo random seed.

Comment: @Kaiido `t` is in `y`, which is prepended to the resulting string.

Comment: @luk2302 right so I wasn't reading correctly ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert each operation and invert the order of the operations. I will give you a breakdown of every operation and leave it to you to actually do the inversion:

Preparation:

- `t = parseInt((+new Date()).toString().substr(11))`: it gets the the last two digits of the current UTC timestamp, aka the 100th and the 1000th of a second. The `|| 1` is just for error handling in case the Date does not give a useful result.
- `y = ('0' + t.toString(16)).substr(-2)`: convert the previous `t` into base 16. The 0 prefix and -2 substring are once again just corner case error handling

Obfuscation:

- `a.split('').map(function(e, i) {
  return String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(0) + i % t);
  }).join('')`: iterate over every char of the input string and apply the inner function:

  - get the char code and add the index modulo `t` and get a String back from that char code
- pass the char transformed string into `obbtoa`:

  - `btoa` the string
  - replace different special characters
- the `y` is prepended to the result string so the decoding can know both the `t` and `y`.

To get an idea of the reversal:

- take the first two characters to get `y`, inverse the operation we used to compute `y` from `t` to get "our" `t`
- inverse the replacements, inverse the `btoa`
- inverse the char transformation by basically doing a `-` instead of a `+`

Comment: "0 prefix and -2 substring" is actually a padStart(2, '0'), to get a fixed length in case it produced 0x0n